# is it possible to get friend list by uid?

Tags: java, facebook

If i have uid of user is there any way to fetch the user list of this user?
i tried "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=UID" but this return permission error.

My purpose is to find out if me and given user has mutual friends of second, third etc. degree.

thank you.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can only retrieve friend lists of users who have authorized your application.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't get users who are not authorized, this will be againts facebook's policy. The only way is to get them to **[give you offline_access](http://modelix.net/2009/09/facebook-connect-working-with-offline-users-data-access/)** and then you can use them any time through the life time of your application.

Comment: thanks dude!! but i actually didn't understand you answer, if you have some tip, please share it with me. Can i also get friend list of users that not authorized in my application?

Comment: @yav, sorry i missed to see some details, i have updated my answer plz check.

Comment: the offline_access extended permission was created for application can interact with FB API with the offline user's creditians. If you need in just retrieving users info - authorizing in application is enough.